# React + Nodejs => Difference between sending functions as props

Tags: reactjs

I am not understanding why I must send this kind of prop for making work:

```
clickToDelete={() => this.deleteElement(item.id)}
```

and

when it is in same file, I musn't write `() =>` :

```
button onClick={this.deleteFirstMovie}>Delete First Element</button>


// moviesList.js

deleteElement = (id) => {
    const copyMovies = [...this.state.movies];
    const indexToDelete = copyMovies.findIndex(element => element === id)
    copyMovies.splice(indexToDelete,1);

    this.setState({
        movies:copyMovies
    })
}

    render () {
        console.log(this.state.movies)
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.movies.map(item => 
                        <li id={item.id} key={item.id}>
                            <ImproveCard title={item.title} director={item.director} clickToDelete={() => this.deleteElement(item.id)} />
                        </li>    
                    )}
                    <button onClick={this.deleteFirstMovie}>Delete First Element</button>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }


// ImproveCard.js

import React from 'react';

const ImproveCard= props => {
    return (
        <div className="movies-list-item">
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
            <p>Director: {props.director}</p>
            <button onClick={props.clickToDelete}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ImproveCard;
```

It is like, when I send like that:

```
clickToDelete={this.deleteElement(item.id)}
```

onClick is calling to delete even if I didn't click it.

Answer (score 1):

Because this invokes the function call `deleteElement(item.id)` immediately and sets its *result* to the `clickToDelete` property:

```
clickToDelete={this.deleteElement(item.id)}
```

And that result is probably not a function.  You don't want to invoke the delete operation immediately upon render, you want to invoke it when you click the element.  So you need to set the `clickToDelete` property to a function, not the *result* of a function.  That's what this is:

```
clickToDelete={() => this.deleteElement(item.id)}
```

Which is just shorter modern syntax (with some subtle differences that shouldn't matter here) for:

```
clickToDelete={function () { this.deleteElement(item.id); }}
```

That way what you're providing is just a function, nothing is invoking it yet.  When you click the element then the element will invoke the function you had provided, and the only line of code in that function is:

```
this.deleteElement(item.id)
```

---

The other example you provide demonstrates this concept as well.  Note that this code *does not* invoke the function:

```
onClick={this.deleteFirstMovie}
```

Because there are no parentheses after the function name.  This is setting the function itself to the `onClick` property, and that function will be invoked when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

So, onClick accept a function that is executed whenever you click on the item.
When you call

```
<button onClick={this.deleteFirstMovie}>Delete First Element</button>
```

you are passing a function, you are not calling it, there are not parenthesis. This is doable only when the handler doesn't need any extra parameter other than eventually the event.

When you do

```
clickToDelete={this.deleteElement(item.id)}
```

you are actually calling the function, not passing it, and the result of that function will become your click handler.
If you want to avoid this behavior, and still be able to pass extra parameters to your handler, you have to use anonymous function like this:

```
() => this.deleteElement(item.id)
```

In this case the handler will be a new function (called anonymous because you're not giving it a name) and when you click the button will call your deleteElement method.

Hope i was clear :)